# Reeded Glass Effect in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, effects

I came across the [reeded glass displacement system on YouWorkForThem](https://www.youworkforthem.com/graphic/E6379/reeded-glass-displacement-system). However, the displacement system is made for Photoshop (which I don't have), and I wanna create a similar effect using GIMP.

[image: Reeded glass effect on YouWorkForThem]

Can anyone show me how can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

GIMP's displacement map filter is located under *Filters > Map > Displace*

To use it you need to create a displacement map image first. I just used the gradient tool here, and duplicated the layers and moved them repeatedly, then merged the layers.

[image]

Here's an example using the displacement filter with the banded image (above) as the input. It's fun to play with. Engage the preview and you can see the image update as you move the sliders.

[image]